# Plotting Shapely polygons on basemap

Tags: python, shapely, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have some polygons and multipolygons created using latitudes and longitudes using shapely(there is no shapefile). I want to plot them using basemap. However they don't show up. When I use matplotlib without using basemap, they show up just fine. But they don't work alongside basemap:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
w, h = maxx - minx, maxy - miny
ax.set_xlim(minx - 0.2 * w, maxx + 0.2 * w)
ax.set_ylim(miny - 0.2 * h, maxy + 0.2 * h)
ax.set_aspect(1)

em = Basemap(
    projection='merc',
    llcrnrlon=minx - 0.2 * w,
    llcrnrlat=miny - 0.2 * h,
    urcrnrlon=maxx + 0.2 * w,
    urcrnrlat=maxy + 0.2 * h,
    lat_ts=0,
    resolution='h')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()

patches = [] 
# Initialize patches to array of shapely Polygons using latitude and longitude

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'm', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))
plt.show()
```

Comment: In any case, basemap is deprecated, I would advise to switch to cartopy before investing too much time in this. https://www.scivision.co/cartopy-replace-deprecated-basemap/

Comment: Can you add a random polygon to make the example fully reproducable? What _exactly_ is your result?